# Creating a function to output a string when the input is negative or zero. First time doing user-defined functions

Tags: c++, function, if-statement

I am trying to create a user-define function in C++ to prevent an endless loop from inputting an incorrect input for a double variable and check if an input is negative or zero. If that's the case the function will go into a do-while loop to ask the user to try again until the value is no longer something other than a double, negative, or zero.

The function fix() is the the user-defined

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

string fix(double x)
{
    string B_error = "B cannot be zero or negative. Please try again: ";
    string H_error = "H cannot be zero or negative. Please try again: ";
    string h_error = "b cannot be zero or negative. Please try again: ";
    string b_error = "h cannot be zero or negative. Please try again: ";
    string r_error = "r cannot be zero or negative. Please try again: ";
    string y_error;

    while (!(cin >> x))
    {
        if (cin.fail())
        {
            cout << "Erroneous input. Please try again:\n";

            cin.clear(); // used to prevent an endless loop if an input type is not an integer
            cin.ignore(10000, '\n');
        }
    }

    if (x == 'B')
        {
            y_error = B_error;


    if (x <= 0)
        {
            do 
            {
                return y_error;
                cin >> x;
            }
            while (x <= 0);
        }
}
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
int selection;
double I, B, H, b, h, r, fix(double);

cout << "Please select the type of beam:\n"
<< "1) I-Beam\n"
<< "2) Rectangular Beam\n"
<< "3) Cylindrical Beam\n";

while (!(cin >> selection) || selection < 1 || selection > 3)
{
    if (cin.fail() || selection < 1 || selection > 3)
    {
        cout << "Erroneous input. Please try again:\n";

        cin.clear(); // used to prevent an endless loop if an input type is not an integer
        cin.ignore(10000, '\n');
    }   
}

switch (selection)
{
    case 1:
        cout << "You have selected I-beam. All inputs must be in inches.\n"
        << "Please input the value for B: ";
        fix(B);


        cout << "Please input the value for H: ";
        fix(H);

        if (H <= 0)
        {
            do 
            {
                cout << "H cannot be zero or negative. Please try again: ";
                cin >> H;
            }
            while (H <= 0);
        }

        cout << "Please input the value for b: ";
        fix(b);

        if (b <= 0)
        {
            do 
            {
                cout << "b cannot be zero or negative. Please try again: ";
                cin >> b;
            }
            while (b <= 0);
        }

        else if (b > B)
        {
            do
            {
                cout << "b cannot be larger than B. Please try again: ";
                cin >> b;
            }
            while (b > B);
        }

        cout << "Please input the value for h: ";
        fix(h);

        if (h <= 0)
        {
            do 
            {
                cout << "h cannot be zero or negative. Please try again: ";
                cin >> h;
            }
            while (h <= 0);
        }

        else if (h > H)
        {
            do
            {
                cout << "h cannot be larger than H. Please try again: ";
                cin >> H;
            }
            while (h > H);
        }

        I = (B*H*H*H - b*h*h*h)/12.;

        cout << "\nResults for an I-beam with B = " << B
        << ", H = " << H << ", b = " << b << ", and h = " << h << endl;
        cout << setfill('-') << setw(32) << "" << endl;
        break;

    case 2:
        cout << "You have selected rectangular beam. All inputs must be in inches.\n"
        << "Please input the value for b: ";
        fix(b);

        if (b <= 0)
        {
            do 
            {
                cout << "b cannot be zero or negative. Please try again: ";
                cin >> b;
            }
            while (b <= 0);
        }

        cout << "Please input the value for h: ";
        fix(h);

        if (h <= 0)
        {
            do 
            {
                cout << "h cannot be zero or negative. Please try again: ";
                cin >> h;
            }
            while (h <= 0);
        }

        I = b*h*h*h/12.;
        cout << "\nResults for a rectangular beam with b = " << b << " and h = " << h << endl;
        cout << setfill('-') << setw(32) << "" << endl;
        break;

    case 3:     
        cout << "You have selected cylindrical beam. All inputs must be in inches.\n"
        << "Please input the value of r: ";
        fix(r);

        if (r <= 0)
        {
            do 
            {
                cout << "r cannot be zero or negative. Please try again: ";
                cin >> r;
            }
            while (r <= 0);
        }

        I = M_PI*pow(r,4)/4.;

        cout << "\nResults for a cylindrical beam with r = " << r << endl;
        cout << setfill('-') << setw(32) << "" << endl;
        break;
}


cout << "The value of the moment of inertia for this beam is: " << I << "in^4" << "\n\n";

return 0;
}
```

Comment: In `if (x == 'B')` how is a `double` going to compare to  `'B'` which is a character? Its always a double. It can't be a character. You can't input `'B'` to the `x` variable.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: `double I, B, H, b, h, r, fix(double);` is the same as `double fix(double);` which I'm 99% sure is not what you want to do there.

Comment: Warning: `return 0;` is a program crasher in a function that returns a `std::string`. It compiles because the compiler can transform the number 0 into a null pointer and then use that null pointer as a `char *` to initialize the temporary string it's returning. All syntactically correct, but logically the program goes BOOM! trying to create a `string` out of a non-existent character array.

Comment: Recommendation: Stop writing code. Come up with a plan. Break the plan down into smaller steps and attack each step one by one, preferably each as it's own individually testable and verifiable function. When you have all of the step-functions figured out, tested, and working, assemble the functions into a program. You'll find problems a lot faster this way and probably find problems one at a time. One bug is easy to solve. Multiple bugs tend gang up on you.

Comment: @drescherjm My understanding is when I use the function fix() such as at line 71 in case 1 as fix(B), B will populate all of the 'x' variables in the fix() function. In regards to your comment, I am trying to see if the newly populated x (which would be B) would be equivalent to B. Then the function would select the appropriate error string and assign it to y_error.

Comment: I figured you wanted something like that. It will not work as you want. I think you want to add an additional parameter to fix to allow specifying what message to display.

Comment: @scohe001 I have removed the fix(double) and the return 0 out of the fix() function. The program now will allow me to input for B then it will say "Press any key to continue . . ." and then will ask for H even when the input was negative or zero.

Comment: You need to run the fix() function on the variables that you want to fix one at a time. The comma operator does not do what you think. Also fix returns a string. Did you want to use the string returned? And fix takes a double by value so it can't modify the variable in the calling scope. For example: `fix(B);` will not change the variable `B` in main() even though a new value could be retrieved in the fix() function.

Comment: @raiool Please don't forget to check answered if someone answered it for you - else it is showing up in the "unanswered" section - but up to you.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the issues. You are confusing instances of classes with functions. Functions don't have to be initialized, instances have to if they are outside of the class.
I wrote some comments along the code. It is still not beautiful but at least it works.

`string FUNCTION(double)` btw. means the function only can or should return a "string". If you are returning nothing the function is written like so `void FUNCTION(double)`.
If your return f.e. a string you have to write something that is receiving the returned string like so:

```c++
#include <iostream>
/*
std::string returning_value;
returning_value = FUNCTION(1.0);
*/
//or

std::string FUNCTION(double function_a); //prototype of the function
//you need this if you write the function underneath the main() function
//The main function is returning "return 0" so since "0" is an "int" 
//meaning main is always "int main()" btw. because it is a function,
//just not some function but the "main function" thats called by the OS

int main()
{
std::string returning_value;
double a = 0.1; //initializing with 0.1
returning_value = FUNCTION(a);
std::cout << returning_value << std::endl;

//and in both cases the function would look like:

return 0;
}

std::string FUNCTION(double function_a)
{

std::string returning_value_a = "This is a string that will be returned";

if(function_a == 0.1)
{
returning_value_a = "This is another string";
}

return returning_value_a;
}
```

Your code with the least amount fixed that you got it at least working
and you can test with how to get the right output you want to get. Have fun :) Hope my answer helps you :)

```c++
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

void fix(double x)
{
    string B_error = "B cannot be zero or negative. Please try again: ";
    string H_error = "H cannot be zero or negative. Please try again: ";
    string h_error = "b cannot be zero or negative. Please try again: ";
    string b_error = "h cannot be zero or negative. Please try again: ";
    string r_error = "r cannot be zero or negative. Please try again: ";
    string y_error;

    while (!(cin >> x))
    {
        if (cin.fail())
        {
            cout << "Erroneous input. Please try again:\n";

            cin.clear(); // used to prevent an endless loop if an input type is not an integer
            cin.ignore(10000, '\n');
        }
    }
//warning: comparing floating point with == or != is unsafe
    if (x == 'B')
        {
            y_error = B_error;


    if (x <= 0)
        {
            do
            {
                cin >> x;
            }
            while (x <= 0);
        }
}

}

int main()
{
int selection;
double I, B, H, b, h, r;
//You need to initialize the variables with a value
I = 1.0;
B = 1.0;
H = 1.0;
b = 1.0;
h = 1.0;
r = 1.0;
//functions don't need to be initialized, thats for Instanzes of classes
//double fix(double);

cout << "Please select the type of beam:\n"
<< "1) I-Beam\n"
<< "2) Rectangular Beam\n"
<< "3) Cylindrical Beam\n";

while (!(cin >> selection) || selection < 1 || selection > 3)
{
    if (cin.fail() || selection < 1 || selection > 3)
    {
        cout << "Erroneous input. Please try again:\n";

        cin.clear(); // used to prevent an endless loop if an input type is not an integer
        cin.ignore(10000, '\n');
    }
}

switch (selection)
{
    case 1:
        cout << "You have selected I-beam. All inputs must be in inches.\n"
        << "Please input the value for B: ";
        fix(B);


        cout << "Please input the value for H: ";
        fix(H);

        if (H <= 0)
        {
            do
            {
                cout << "H cannot be zero or negative. Please try again: ";
                cin >> H;
            }
            while (H <= 0);
        }

        cout << "Please input the value for b: ";
        fix(b);

        if (b <= 0)
        {
            do
            {
                cout << "b cannot be zero or negative. Please try again: ";
                cin >> b;
            }
            while (b <= 0);
        }

        else if (b > B)
        {
            do
            {
                cout << "b cannot be larger than B. Please try again: ";
                cin >> b;
            }
            while (b > B);
        }

        cout << "Please input the value for h: ";
        fix(h);

        if (h <= 0)
        {
            do
            {
                cout << "h cannot be zero or negative. Please try again: ";
                cin >> h;
            }
            while (h <= 0);
        }

        else if (h > H)
        {
            do
            {
                cout << "h cannot be larger than H. Please try again: ";
                cin >> H;
            }
            while (h > H);
        }

        I = (B*H*H*H - b*h*h*h)/12.;

        cout << "\nResults for an I-beam with B = " << B
        << ", H = " << H << ", b = " << b << ", and h = " << h << endl;
        cout << setfill('-') << setw(32) << "" << endl;
        break;

    case 2:
        cout << "You have selected rectangular beam. All inputs must be in inches.\n"
        << "Please input the value for b: ";
        fix(b);

        if (b <= 0)
        {
            do
            {
                cout << "b cannot be zero or negative. Please try again: ";
                cin >> b;
            }
            while (b <= 0);
        }

        cout << "Please input the value for h: ";
        fix(h);

        if (h <= 0)
        {
            do
            {
                cout << "h cannot be zero or negative. Please try again: ";
                cin >> h;
            }
            while (h <= 0);
        }

        I = b*h*h*h/12.;
        cout << "\nResults for a rectangular beam with b = " << b << " and h = " << h << endl;
        cout << setfill('-') << setw(32) << "" << endl;
        break;

    case 3:
        cout << "You have selected cylindrical beam. All inputs must be in inches.\n"
        << "Please input the value of r: ";
        fix(r);

        if (r <= 0)
        {
            do
            {
                cout << "r cannot be zero or negative. Please try again: ";
                cin >> r;
            }
            while (r <= 0);
        }

        I = M_PI*pow(r,4)/4.;

        cout << "\nResults for a cylindrical beam with r = " << r << endl;
        cout << setfill('-') << setw(32) << "" << endl;
        break;
}


cout << "The value of the moment of inertia for this beam is: " << I << "in^4" << "\n\n";

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I had to add another function to check if B < b and H < h and add a do-while loop after the while loop in the fix function.

Here's my code with the fix:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

void fix(double &x)
{

    while (!(cin >> x))
    {
        if (cin.fail())
        {
            cout << "Erroneous input. Please try again:\n";

            cin.clear(); // used to prevent an endless loop if an input type is not a         double
            cin.ignore(10000, '\n');
        }
    }

    string return_x = "This cannot be zero or negative. Please try again: ";

    while (x <= 0)
    {
        cout << return_x << endl;
        cin >> x;
    }

}

void fix2(double &x, double &y)
{
    while (x < y)
    {
        cout << x << " cannot be less than " << y << endl;
        fix(y);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int selection;
    double I = 1.0;
    double B = 1.0;
    double H = 1.0;
    double b = 1.0;
    double h = 1.0;
    double r = 1.0;

    cout << "Please select the type of beam:\n"
         << "1) I-Beam\n"
         << "2) Rectangular Beam\n"
         << "3) Cylindrical Beam\n";

    while (!(cin >> selection) || selection < 1 || selection > 3)
    {
        if (cin.fail() || selection < 1 || selection > 3)
        {
            cout << "Erroneous input. Please try again:\n";

            cin.clear(); // used to prevent an endless loop if an input type is not an integer
            cin.ignore(10000, '\n');
        }
    }

    switch (selection)
    {
        case 1:
            cout << "You have selected I-beam. All inputs must be in inches.\n"
                    << "Please input the value for B: ";
            fix(B);

            cout << "Please input the value for H: ";
            fix(H);

            cout << "Please input the value for b: ";
            fix(b);
            fix2(B, b);

            cout << "Please input the value for h: ";
            fix(h);
            fix2(H, h);

            I = (B * H * H * H - b * h * h * h) / 12.;

            cout << "\nResults for an I-beam with B = " << B << ", H = " << H
                 << ", b = " << b << ", and h = " << h << endl;
            cout << setfill('-') << setw(32) << "" << endl;
            break;

        case 2:
            cout << "You have selected rectangular beam. All inputs must be in inches.\n"
                 << "Please input the value for b: ";
            fix(b);

            cout << "Please input the value for h: ";
            fix(h);

            I = b * h * h * h / 12.;
            cout << "\nResults for a rectangular beam with b = " << b
                    << " and h = " << h << endl;
            cout << setfill('-') << setw(32) << "" << endl;
            break;

        case 3:
            cout << "You have selected cylindrical beam. All inputs must be in inches.\n"
                 << "Please input the value of r: ";
            fix(r);

            I = M_PI * pow(r, 4) / 4.;

            cout << "\nResults for a cylindrical beam with r = " << r << endl;
            cout << setfill('-') << setw(32) << "" << endl;
            break;
    }

    cout << "The value of the moment of inertia for this beam is: " << I
         << "in^4" << "\n\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Careful with `M_PI` it's non-Standard. It would really suck if you handed this in and the marker's compiler didn't define `M_PI`.